# jQuery 1.9.0 strange $.get behaviour

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$("#workout-switcher .button").on('click', function(){
   console.log('first test'); // this is logged
   $.get("/ajax/set-workout.php", { 'request' : id, 'date' : date },
      function(data){
         console.log('second test'); // this is not logged
      },'json'
   );
});
```

This works perfectly in jQuery 1.8.3, that is: the `first test` is logged into the console, then the `get` request is sent and successfully executed, then the `second test` is logged into the console.

This is what happens in jQuery 1.9.0: `first test` fires, `get` successfully fires, but `second test` is **not** logged into the console.

Any idea what's wrong here?

**EDIT**

When I changed $.get to $.ajax, it started working. Obviously a jQuery 1.9.0 bug.

Comment: what does your php return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. I don't think it has to? At least in 1.8.3 it didn't need to.

Comment: What messages did you get from the [JQuery Migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the upgrade guide:http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

"jQuery.ajax returning a JSON result of an empty string
Prior to 1.9, an ajax call that expected a return data type of JSON or JSONP would consider a return value of an empty string to be a success case, but return a null to the success handler or promise. As of 1.9, an empty string returned for JSON data is considered to be malformed JSON (because it is); this will now throw an error. Use the error handler to catch such cases. "